# Django - Logging not overriding default settings

Tags: python, django, debugging, logging

I'm currently developing a site using Django 1.6.2 and i'm not being able to make the logging configuration correctly.

I've set 'LOGGING' on the settings file, but it seems to be ignored. Here's my settings file:

```
    # Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
    import os
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

    # Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
    # See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

    # SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
    SECRET_KEY = "duummy"

    # SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
    DEBUG = True

    TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

    ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


    # Application definition

    INSTALLED_APPS = (
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'channels'
    )

    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    )

    ROOT_URLCONF = 'my_app.urls'

    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'my_app.wsgi.application'


    # Database
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': 'db.sqlite3',
        }
    }

    CACHES = {
        'default': {
            'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
            'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
        }
    }

    # Internationalization
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

    TIME_ZONE = 'Brazil/East'

    USE_I18N = True

    USE_L10N = True

    USE_TZ = True


    # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

    STATIC_URL = '/static/'

    # Logging
    #

    LOGGING_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'logs/')

    LOGGING = {
        'version': 1,
        'disable_existing_loggers': True,
        'formatters': {
            'verbose': {
                'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
            },
            'simple': {
                'format': '%(asctime)s - %(module)s -> %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
            }
        },
        'filters': {
            'require_debug_true': {
                '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
            }
         },
        'handlers': {
            'console':{
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                'formatter': 'verbose'
            },
            'debug_log_handler': {
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
                'filename': os.path.join(LOGGING_DIR, 'debug_log'),
                'formatter':'verbose'
            },
            'db_log_handler': {
                'level': 'ERROR',
                'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
                'filename': os.path.join(LOGGING_DIR, 'db_log'),
                'when':'D',
                'interval':1,
                'formatter':'simple'
            },
            'request_log_handler': {
                'level': 'ERROR',
                'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
                'filename': os.path.join(LOGGING_DIR, 'request_log'),
                'when':'D',
                'interval':1,
                'formatter':'simple'
            },
            'site_log_handler': {
                'level': 'ERROR',
                'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
                'filename': os.path.join(LOGGING_DIR, 'log'),
                'when':'D',
                'interval':1,
                'formatter':'simple'
            }
        },
        'loggers': {
            'django': {
                'handlers': ['console', 'debug_log_handler'],
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'propagate': True,
                'filters': ['require_debug_true']
            },
            'django.db.backends': {
                'handlers': ['db_log_handler'],
                'level': 'ERROR',
                'propagate': True
            },
            'django.request': {
                'handlers': ['request_log_handler'],
                'level': 'ERROR',
                'propagate': True
            },
            'test': {
                'handlers': ['site_log_handler'],
                'level': 'ERROR',
                'propagate': True
            },
        }
    }
```

When I run the server, the console is outputting info like:

```
[13/Mar/2014 01:25:12] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2015
```

It's not printing the debug information, neither it's printing in the format that i've specified for the console.

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you ran the server, and seemingly did a 'GET /', Django would have logged the request to the 'django.request' logger.  And since you set LOGGING.disable_existing_loggers to True, it would have to use the django.request settings you configured.

In LOGGING.loggers, you set django.request's level to 'ERROR'.  However, 4XXs are only logged as WARNINGS according to [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/logging/#id2).  Only 5XXs are logged as ERRORs.

Answer (score 0):

Django only logs to four loggers, as documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#id2): `django`, `django.request`, `django.db.backends` and `django.security`. The first of these is not logged to directly, you've set the levels of the next two to `ERROR` - which means they won't log any `DEBUG` messages - and the last of these is only logged to if a security issue occurs.

Try setting the `test` logger's level to `DEBUG`, adding `console_handler` to its `handlers` list and logging some `DEBUG` messages to it from one of your views - you should see some output.